# How can I use height patches to generate terrain such as what was used to create Abzu?

Tags: unity, terrain

Last year's GDC was pretty inspirational for me and Matt's talk about GiantSquid's landscape creating workflow was the best of all. If you haven't seen it I highly recommend you to check it out.

I'm a Unity dev and I'm aware of the fact that Abzu was done with UE and the tools they used in this landscape creation and customizing was custom built.

Although I'd eventually like to create similar tools for terrain generation via mashing height patches and enabling different surfaces blending, terrain stamps, and such, the first thing I should ask should be about the level terrain bit.

How can I use height patches to generate a terrain (like sand) and then blending them together with something else without extra sculpting (like rock protruding from the sand surface)?

Comment: If I recall correctly there were several different tools and workflows discussed in that talk. Can you pick just one to ask about first, and describe in detail what aspects you need help implementing? You can always post a second question to ask about the next part and so on. Generally a narrow, well-defined question will get higher-quality answers, faster.

Comment: @DMGregory thanks for the comment! question is now edited!